# Use LASSO & bootstrapping for inference stats - no machine learning

Tags: feature-selection, lasso, methodology

I have a simple question: it is valid to use a LASSO model for variable selection in a small dataset? I won't do any machine learning. The goal is to use LASSO for variable selection instead of stepwise regression.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Edit: The dataset consists of three categories of behavioral variables and the dependent variable of group (binary variable). My boss suggested stepwise regression (which would be conducted three times, yielding the most statistically significant variable selection). As this procedure has some shortcomings I thought about possible alternatives.

Comment: Doing model-selection/variable-selection (by whatever means) on the same data you're using for inference is problematic unless you have a way of incorporating the effect of the selection on the subsequent inference. Since this is usually tricky, people often tend to use data-splitting to avoid that impact.

Comment: The text raises questions.  (1) How small is "small," exactly?  (2) What is "machine learning"?  I'm not being facetious--the meaning of this phrase seems to vary from one practitioner and community to another.  (3) Why does it matter whether what you do is called "machine learning" or not?  (4) What is the meaning of "valid"?  Mathematically sound? Legally justifiable? Consistent with your assumptions?  Reliable for your scientific objectives?  If it's any of the latter, then of course we need to be told your assumptions and objectives in order to answer.

Comment: 1) sample size is n=120 2) I meant  conducting the cross validation procedure to yield out of sample estimations 3) it matters because the sample size is clearly too small to yield reliable out of sample estimations 4) reliable for my scientific objectives and on the same hand mathematically sound; to give you some more information, I have a bunch of behavioural variables (sociodemographics, cognitive performance, etc) from which I like to select the most statistically meaningful. My professor suggested to use stepwise regression. As this has some shortcomings, I thought about alternatives